# Looping through a 2d session array shopping cart php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Im buliding a shopping cart and want to use a 2d array to store the items ID and quantity. When the user goes to the shopping cart I want to be able to grab the Items ID from the array and output the items details from the database

```
/**************** Adding to the 2d array ***********************/
    //Check to see if variable isset and then add item to shopping cart
    //$itemID is the ID of the product
    //$quantity is the quantity of the product they wish to order
    if(isset($_GET['add'])){
        $itemID = $_GET['add'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = array("id" => $itemID,"quantity" => $quantity);
        header('xxx');//stops user contsanlty adding on refresh
    }

    /******************** Looping through the array  **********************/
        //need to loop through grab the item ID
        //then pull what we need from the database  

        //This is where I want to grab the id from the array and query the database

        $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
        foreach ($cart as $value ){
        //works like it should
            foreach ( $value as $key=> $final_val ){
                echo $key;
                echo ':';
                echo $final_val;
                echo '<br/>';
            }
                echo '<br/>';
        }
```

The array outputs like so

id:1
quantity:5

id:2
quantity:1

Im having a little trouble figuring out how to seperate the ID and quantity so that I can query the database with the item ID.

Comment: can you write what is the expected output?

Comment: Try `foreach ( $value[$itemID] as $final_val ){`

Comment: Hi guys thanks for helping but Arun below gave me what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ( $value as $key=> $final_val ){
              if($key=='id')
              {
                echo $key;
                echo ':';
                echo $final_val;
                echo '<br/>';
              }
            }
```

or you can directly use like `$value['id']`
something like this will help you..please try.
is this you need?

Comment: Arun you are a legend, that worked perfectly thank you. I knew it was only a minor problem but didnt think on using an IF statement

Comment: Please select this as best answer by clicking the tick mark ,if you think so :)